# Angular Material md-menu position issue

Tags: angular, angular-material

Im using the md-component for Angular 2 from Angular Material. I'm following the docs instructions on how to implement it but the menu opens up below the trigger.

Here is my code

```
  <button class="menu-button" md-icon-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
    <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
  </button>
  <md-menu #menu="mdMenu" class="popup-menu">
    <button md-menu-item>
      <md-icon>dialpad</md-icon>
      <span>Menu option 1</span>
    </button>
    <button md-menu-item disabled>
      <md-icon>voicemail</md-icon>
      <span>Menu option 2</span>
    </button>
    <button md-menu-item>
      <md-icon>notifications_off</md-icon>
      <span>Menu option 3</span>
    </button>
  </md-menu>
```

Is there something im missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the md-menu :

```
<md-menu #appMenu="mdMenu" x-position="before" y-position="below"  >
```

You can try x-position="after" or y-position="above"

I found the info here : [angular material menu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular2-material/menu)

It worked for me on the 2.0.0-alpha.8.2 version of material.